# How to calculate the PPI from Resolution X and Y?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

Right now I'm building a photo hosting website.

I tried to get the resolution of the images we upload.

I'm familiar with the (PPI) resolution we use in Photoshop. When I tried to get the resolution of the image through RMagick, it gave me two values, `Resolution X` and `Resolution Y`. How can I calculate the exact resolution from the X and Y values?

Comment: The ppi of an image is determined solely by the device on which it is displayed. It is a physical measurement. That combined with the resolution of the image (`Resolution X` and `Resolution Y`, or how many pixels wide and high it is) determine the physical size (in inches) of the displayed image. The ppi used by Photoshop is nothing more than a guess as to the physical resolution of the device on which an image might be displayed.

Comment: @beaker So, what should I include in my website, PPI or DPI? And how to calculate it with horizontal and vertical resolutions?

Comment: Perhaps the answer here will address some of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516461/very-strange-ppi-of-png